# Confusion in grobner basis and ideals generated by matrices.

Tags: affine-varieties, groebner-basis, groebner-generators

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MzElOy1tgJGzZkCpzY8d_msKHuV-03kx/view?usp=sharing

Here is a link to Strumfels 1990 paper(**Grobner Basis and stanley decomposition of determinantal rings (pdf pg-137)**).

Theorem $1$ in this paper is stated as follows:

> The set of $(r+1 \times r+1) $ minors of the matrix forms a Grobner basis of *$I_r$* with respect to the lexicographical ordering $x_{1,n} > x_{1,n-1} > \cdots x_{m,1}$ where *$I_r$* denotes the vanishing sub-ideals of the affine subvarieties of matrices of rank at most $r < min\{m,n\}$.

I don't understand the term **vanishing sub-ideals of the affine subvarieties of matrices of rank at most $r < min\{m,n\}$** .

My doubt also lies in the fact does it imply somehow that the set of all $k \times k $ minors of a  generic $n \times n$ matrix forms a grobner basis of the ideal $I_k(X)$ where $I_k(X)$ denotes the ideal generated by $k \times k$ minors of the matrix $X$ of the form $[a_1 \cdots a_k \mid 1 \cdots k]$ where $1 \cdots k$ are columns and $a_1 \cdots a_k$ are rows.

Edit 1:
(i)$C_k:= \{a = (a1, ··· , ak) |1 ≤a1< ··· <ak≤n\}$ denotes the collection of all ordered k-tuples from $\{1, ··· , n\}. $

(ii) Given $ a = (a_1, ..., a_k)∈C_k$;

$X^a= [a_1, ··· , a_k|1, 2, ..., k]$denotes the $k ×k $ minor of the matrix $X$, with $a_1, ..., a_k$ as rows and $1, ..., k$ as columns.

•$S_k:= \{X^a:a ∈C_k\}$and $I_k$ denotes the ideal generated by $S_k$ in the polynomial ring R

Lemma 4.2 **The Groebner Basis of the ideal $I_k$ with respect to the monomial ordering is the set $S_k$**.

The proof  uses Buchberger's criterion

$S(X^c,X^d) \to_{(S_k)} r$. Then the set $S(X^c,X^d) - \sum_{a_i \in C_i}(h_i.X^{a_i}) = r$.

If $X$ is generic, then the set of all $k \times k$ monomial ordering forms a Groebner basis with respect to the the chosen monomial ordering.(strumfels 1990)(**)

Therefore there exists $[a_1,a_2,...,a_k \mid b_1 \cdots b_k]$  such that $\prod_{i=1}^k(\chi_{a_i.b_i})$ divides the $LT(r)$. We see that if $b_k=k$ then we are done.

Let $X$ be generic symmetric .Then, $a_k=k$ and $b_k \ge k+1$ imply that the minor belongs to the set $S_k$.(**Can someone explain this property of generic symmetric matrix?**)

Let $X$ be generic. Then, for any $a_k$ and under the condition $b_k \ge k+1$, then $\chi_{a_k.b_k} | LT(r)$ but $\chi_{a_k.b_k}$ doesn't divide any term of the elements in $S_k$. (**Also I need some help in this property of generic symmetric matrix?**)

I dont understand the (**) as to where it is mentioned in the paper .

Edit 2:I was going through the proof and I got stuck in the two properties of the generic matrices.Can someone explain them to me ?

Comment: I am unable to access your Google drive document : Google needs authorization that visibly needs you to be present, and how can Google know the e-mail address of the asker ? You should consider a different way to post this document.

Comment: https://eudml.org/doc/174163 . Is this link working for you?I had downloaded it from this link a week back ,it was working but it is not now.

Comment: I think you'll be able to access now . Can you check once?

Comment: I have made the drive link accessible to all . I am not sure what to do after this.

Comment: It works. I hadn't clicked on the (new) google drive link

Answer (score 1):

He's just freely using some well-known facts. First, the matrices with rank at most $r < \min\{m, n\}$ are those for which all $(r+1) \times (r+1)$ minors vanish. Second, the ideal generated by these minors is a radical ideal, so it's precisely equal to the vanishing ideal of the set of matrices with rank at most $r$. Hence the quotient is exactly the coordinate ring of that set of matrices, which is an affine algebraic subvariety of the full affine algebraic variety of matrices. (He could perhaps say "ideal" instead of "subideal", though that's a matter of taste.)

I don't know why you're suggesting you can restrict the column indices to $1, \ldots, k$. I don't think there's any hope that anything like that is true.

See [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43965/how-many-minors-i-need-to-check-to-conclude-all-minors-will-vanish) for related discussion and further details. (Beware minor notational mismatches.)

Comment: P.Swanson can you go through my edit .I am not able to attach the paper.This is from Journal Of Symbolic Computation. I am unable to upload the paper using drive link and also the internet link has expired but I have attached the entire relevant section.Can you help me out please?

Comment: @Antimony The relevant section is a bit garbled. The ideal $I_k$ is different from the one in the Sturmfels paper in your Google Drive link. I cannot make any sense of the key line with (**).

Comment: Do I mail you the pdf along with my doubt? Will it be a bit more convenient?I am very stuck in this part and I desperately need some help..

Comment: @Antimony It's best to just cite the paper. I probably have access to it, unless it's unusually obscure. If this was your question the whole time, you should probably have included it from the beginning.

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jsc.2018.06.011

Comment: @Antimony I believe the authors are using $I_k(X)$ and $I_k$ to mean related but different things. $I_k(X)$ is the ideal generated by all $k \times k$ minors, essentially as in Sturmfels' paper, while $I_k$ is the ideal generated by those $k \times k$ minors using the first $k$ columns. The final paragraph of the proof of Lemma 4.2 bridges the gap between these. (I confess I did not read that carefully.)

Comment: Where did strumfels mention the idea that k*k minors generate $I_k$.Is it the theorem 1 in the strumfels paper?Also I am not sure how are they linking$ I_k$ and $I_k(X)$ using the last paragraph.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126102/discussion-between-joshua-p-swanson-and-antimony).

Comment: P.Swanson I still have two doubts 1)If the theorem holds or if there is a similar theorem (that $k \times k$ minors generate the ideal $I_k(X)$) when $X$ is a vandermonde matrix . 2)I am stuck in the part where the authors use the properties of a generic matrix in the lemma. Given my very small exposure,to the subject,I am unable to see if 1 has a solution and I do need some guidance.